# border of table as picture is not working

Tags: html, css, border

I have the following code in JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56mpJ/2/

What I am trying to do is to have the border of the table as a picture that I take from the internet 
I obviously tried

`border-image: url(http://img.docstoccdn.com/thumb/orig/895007.png)`

But unfortunately all I see is a black border..  Any way to help please?

Comment: I can see that image. Which browser you're on?

Comment: Internet explorer 9! You can see it in the fiddle?

Comment: No version of IE support `border-image`. http://caniuse.com/border-image

Answer (score 1):

border-image support is limited, [see caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image)

your demo works for me in chrome/windows
if I where you, I'd use `background-image` for outer border, and simple border for cels